# How to remove local from google fonts

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

I am using google fonts by something like below

`url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,300,600,700,800);`

Result css coming from api is like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light Italic'), local('OpenSans-LightItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v14/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxhgVThLs8Y7ETJzDCYFCSLE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
```

Then suppose that user has a different style font with same name on his computer, I believe `local('Open Sans Light Italic'), local('OpenSans-LightItalic'),` will cause that fonts to be loaded

Is there any option in the request to prevent local, and just having `url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v14/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxhgVThLs8Y7ETJzDCYFCSLE.woff2)` in css

Comment: The answer's already in your question: remove the bits you don't want. So that means copying the CSS you already pasted here, removing the bits that you don't want, and then just saving that to a file and pointing to that file instead of to google's magic URL in a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">`

Answer (score 0):

Local fonts are usually placed after needed fonts, so if needed font wasn't render, the local font will be applied. It prevents user from looking at incorrect rendered fonts and so on. I'm looking at `@font-face` that you posted, and it looks like `Open Sans` that you're importing is the same, as default `Open Sans`.

**UPDATE**

*"The problem I am facing is on one computer font is not rendered correctly."*

To render fonts properly on all platforms you need to apply this CSS properties:

```
/* Render fonts properly on all platforms */
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

You can apply it to specific tag/class/etc., but the easiest way is to apply it globally to all elements like so:

```
* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

I had the same problem and it helped me. Hope, it will solve your issue too.

Comment: I am not good at fonts, The problem I am facing is on one computer font is not rendered correctly on `ie`, so I was suspicious that he might have some wrong local fonts and the css generated by google first looking at local and it finds the local font and load that one

Comment: Yeah, on that computer only `ie` is not working, I checked other computers same version of ie is showing fonts correctly